# select name from customers as @myvariable // dynamic AS in sql

Tags: sql, select

```
DECLARE @myvariable VARCHAR(100)
SET @myvariable = 'mytext'

SELECT Name FROM Customers AS @myvariable
```

How would one go about doing that?

**Answer to Gareth:**
This would allow me to retain the original name of the column when doing something like this:

```
declare @myvariable varchar(20)
set @myvariable='Name'

select case @myvariable when 'Name' then Name
                        when 'Id' then Id
       end
          as Name

from Customers
```

Right now, when the value of @myvariable changes, the colum name won't, but I need it to be the same as @myvariable.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that? I cannot envisage any scenario where a dynamic alias would be useful. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to acheive so perhaps an alterative can be suggested.

Comment: edited post to answer the question

Comment: I'm still not sure why you would need the column name to be dynamic, unless your column names are feed directly through to your UI, which is not a good idea anyway. However, I do understand what you are trying to do, and dynamic SQL is your best approach, as set out in @KDiTraglia's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work

```
DECLARE @myvariable VARCHAR(100)
SET @myvariable = 'mytext'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(200)

SET @sql = 'SELECT Name AS ' + QUOTENAME(@MyVariable)  + ' FROM Customers'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: It is would probably be wise to use `QUOTENAME(@MyVariable)` when building your SQL statement since @MyVariable could contain spaces/reserved characters, or be an SQL keyword which would cause the execution to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to ask, what you need to use is PL/SQL, my understanding of your question is you want to have a program that you want to enter in a variable name it output the results.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FindCustomer(customerName IN STRING) AS
BEGIN
     SELECT NAME INTO CUSTNAME FROM CUSTOMER WHERE NAME = customerName;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CUSTNAME);         
END FindCustomer;
/
PROMPT 'Input Customer\'s name';
ACCEPT temp;
EXECUTE FindCustomer(&temp);
```

I'm not completely sure if that is right seeing as I have not tested it but, that is a PL/SQL function that will in theory return you the Name of a customer that you input into the script via keyboard or whatever input. If you want to learn more about PL/SQL I suggest you go [here](http://plsql-tutorial.com/index.htm)

Comment: Ahhh obviously I misunderstood the question, but I'm just going to leave this here, cause I worked hard on it, and it may strike interest in you.

Comment: even though the OP isn't using Oracle, this isn't valid PL/SQL. `string` should be `varchar2` and you need to declare the variable `custname`, `custname customer.name%type`.

Comment: Thanks for that it was just something that I sprung up on top of my head. So I knew there were errors but it gave an overall impression of what I meant.